# ELF header present in executable image

Tags: assembly, linker, elf

I am trying to write a 64-bit kernel.
However, I found something weird in the assembled and linked elf file.
This is a stub for the kernel right now.

stub.asm

```
[bits 64]

KERNEL_STACK_SIZE equ 65536 ; 64 KiB stack

;Reserve space for stack
section .bss
    global kernel_stack
kernel_stack:
    resb KERNEL_STACK_SIZE

section .text
    global kernel_start
kernel_start:
kernel_end:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp kernel_end
```

and this is the linker script that I use with x86_64-elf-ld (gcc cross-compiler).

```
ENTRY(kernel_start);

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x300000;

    .text : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(.data);
    }
    .rodata : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(.rodata*);
    }
    .bss : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss);
    }
}
```

The linker script works but the elf generated is over 1 MiB in size (1049280 bytes exactly).
The entry point is valid and at 0x300000, but it is present at an offset of 0x100000 in the file and the elf program header tells to load the section from beginning of the file (including all the headers) to end of .text section at 0x200000.

Is something wrong with the linker script?

Comment: Is the single assembler fil all you currently have? How do you build and link the kernel?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, it's the only assembler file I am using right now. I use `nasm -f elf64 -o kernel.o kernel.asm` and `x86_64-elf-ld -o kernel kernel.o -T link.ld` to build and link. These commands are in a makefile.

Comment: I believe the x86-64 linker has a maximum page size default of of 0x100000 (1mb). Try changing your linker command line to include `-z max-page-size=0x1000` . This would set it to 4k.

Comment: OK, that helped. Thank you.